Flask authorization in ldap
Good afternoon. I need to connect Active Directory (LDAP) authorization to flask. We managed to do this using the flask_ldap3_login library. However, I need access to a specific page to be allowed only to users who are in the specified Active Directory group. I did not find such a parameter in the standard library.
My script:
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, session, render_template_string
import mysql.connector
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, UserMixin, current_user, login_required
from flask_ldap3_login.forms import LDAPLoginForm
from functools import wraps


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

# Setup LDAP Configuration Variables. Change these to your own settings.
# All configuration directives can be found in the documentation.

# Hostname of your LDAP Server
app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'mdc.test.local'

# Base DN of your directory
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'DC=test,DC=local'

# Users DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = 'OU=Domain Users'

app.config['LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE'] = 'SUBTREE'

# The RDN attribute for your user schema on LDAP
app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn'

# The Attribute you want users to authenticate to LDAP with.
app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'sAMAccountName'

# The Username to bind to LDAP with
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = 'CN=test,OU=Test,OU=Domain Users,DC=test,DC=local'

# The Password to bind to LDAP with
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

login_manager = LoginManager(app)              # Setup a Flask-Login Manager
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app)          # Setup a LDAP3 Login Manager.

# Create a dictionary to store the users in when they authenticate
# This example stores users in memory.
users = {}


# Declare an Object Model for the user, and make it comply with the
# flask-login UserMixin mixin.
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, dn, username, data):
        self.dn = dn
        self.username = username
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.dn

    def get_id(self):
        return self.dn
# Declare a User Loader for Flask-Login.
# Simply returns the User if it exists in our 'database', otherwise
# returns None.
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    if id in users:
        return users[id]
    return None


# Declare The User Saver for Flask-Ldap3-Login
# This method is called whenever a LDAPLoginForm() successfully validates.
# Here you have to save the user, and return it so it can be used in the
# login controller.
@ldap_manager.save_user
def save_user(dn, username, data, memberships):
    user = User(dn, username, data)
    users[dn] = user
    return user

@app.route("/index")
@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not current_user or current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    print(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', title="Sysadmin")

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    # Instantiate a LDAPLoginForm which has a validator to check if the user
    # exists in LDAP.
    form = LDAPLoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Successfully logged in, We can now access the saved user object
        # via form.user.
        login_user(form.user)  # Tell flask-login to log them in.
        return redirect('/')  # Send them home

    
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

def ldap_groups(groups):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.is_authenticated:
                return ldap.unauthorized()
            elif not any(group in groups for group in current_user.data.memberOf):
                return ldap.unauthorized()
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator

@app.route('/admin')
@ldap_groups(['CN=testgr,OU=Test,OU=Domain Users,DC=test,DC=local'])
def admin():
    return 'Welcome, admin!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

I tried to set up filtering by groups using the def ldap_groups(groups) function. But when I try to connect to /admin, I get the error: AttributeError: 'CaseInsensitiveDict' object has no attribute 'memberOf'
